# Flexbox div text wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make text in my flexbox layout wrap.

**Code:** https://jsfiddle.net/u2oswnth/2/

```css
.child {
  border: solid 1px;
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  width: 100px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child left">
    Left!
  </div>
  <div class="child right">
    I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!!
  </div>
</div>
```

**What I have:** When exceeding frame width, `.right` `div` falls to next row.

**What I want:** When exceeding frame width, words in `.right` `div` start wrapping, two columns stay side-by-side, forming single row.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `flex-wrap: nowrap;`. By using `flex-wrap: wrap;` you are telling the `.right` `div` to wrap onto a new line if it runs out of space. As you only want the text itself to wrap you need to use `flex-wrap: nowrap;` to keep `.right` on the same line. The text will automatically wrap when there is not enough space.

- Change `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `flex-wrap: nowrap;` on `.container`

```css
.child {
  border: solid 1px;
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  width: 100px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child left">
    Left!
  </div>
  <div class="child right">
    I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought `flex-wrap: wrap;` is about wrapping text, not divs. Silly me =-)

Comment: No problem, I thought that was your line of thinking when I read your question. :)

Comment: Make sure to use `flex-wrap: nowrap` and NOT `flex-wrap: no-wrap` - the latter is not valid.

Comment: Well spotted @DouglasTylerGordon, thanks for letting me know. Answer corrected accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

NOTE: There is no need to apply `"display: flex"` on child class and `flex-wrap: nowrap;` on container class because bydefault it is `nowrap`. Below is updated answer and WORKS!!.

```
.child {
  border: solid 1px;
}
.left {
  width: 100px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
} 

<div class="container">
  <div class="child left">
    Left!
  </div>
  <div class="child right">
    I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `flex-wrap: nowrap;`

Please note that `flex-wrap: no-wrap;` (**no-wrap with a dash**) is NOT a valid value. Here's the doc reference about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap